# Trouble changing a global variable in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

I'm trying to work out the last digit of a bar code however I'm having trouble with the second and last while loops.

They don't assign any new values to the variables `total` or `mOf10`. It instead leaves them as 0 and I don't understand why.

```
while True:

    number = input("Enter a 7 digit number please.")
    if len(number) == 7:
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number")
        else:
            break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")

print(number) #DELETE THIS BIT LATER!
i = 0
total = 0

while (i < 7 == True):
    global total
    f = str(number)[i]
    if int(f) % 2 == 1:
        total = total + int(f) * 3
    else:
        total = total + int(f)
    i += 1

print(total)

mOf10 = 0

while True:
    global mOf10
    if mOf10 >= total:
        break
    else:
        mOf10 += 10

finalD = mOf10 - total
print(finalD)
```

It prints out what ever 7 digit number you put in however it doesn't output the total or multiple of 10 as anything. They just come out as 0.

My teachers only solution to this was a lot of if/else statements.

Comment: you dont need to use global inside the while loop unless its a function

Comment: `total` here is not a Global variable. It is in same scope as main

Comment: neither is `mOf10`

Comment: If you remove the line `global total` and `global mOf10`, this should give you desired output

Comment: my friend `i<7==True` would always be false! try `(i<7)==True` or just `i<7`

Comment: i took that out but it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but I can tell you what the problem is for which the value of `total` is not changing. The problem here is in the `condition` for the `while` loop. ie, the `while (i < 7 == True)`.

```
>>> i<7
True 
>>> i<7 == True
False
```

As you can see, the control never enters the while loop as the condition returns `False`.

Instead just do `while(i<7)` . That should solve it.

Note : the use of `global` in the code is wrong, as the scope of the `total` and `mOf10` are local itself.

**Edit :**
The reason for the odd behaviour is due to comparison operators having the **same precedence** and due to the **chaining of the operators**, where in for python something like `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`.

> According to Python docs :
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
>   comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
>   a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

We know here :

```
>>> i < 7
True
>>> 7 == True
False
```

And due to the chaining of operators the whole condition in turn becomes `i < 7 and 7 == True` . And since `7==True` is `False`, the condition in the end evaluates to `False` .

Comment: Even better, replace the `i=0, while i < 7, i++` construct with the more pythonic `for i in range(7)`.

Comment: Yes, that is better. Just pointing out the OP's problem here though.

Comment: Yep, comment was aimed more at OP than you!

Comment: Glad to help, and learn something in return. I too just learnt that a quirk  like this is there. Am guessing this happens due to **precedence** playing a role. Will update the answer with deeper explanation in a while.

Comment: @SleepingSoul , check the Edit for full explanation.

Comment: It should be pointed out that because of this `total` is always zero, thus `mOf10` will be equal to `total` and the last while loop breaks immediately

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons are of equal precedence..

`a<b<c` are evaluated as `a<b  and   b<c`

So in your case `i<7==True` is evaluated as `i<7 and 7==True` implying either 
  1. `True and False`  => `False`  **OR**
 
  2. `False and False` => `False`

So it is always `False`

For reference see...
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

And please do the needful for the usage of `global`